# characters to doubles R

Tags: r

I create a frame from different vectors

```
pat1<-c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
pat2<-c(1:5)
pat3<-seq(1,10, by=2)
pat4<-seq(-5,3, by=2)
pat5<-c(pat1+pat2)
variables<-c("a","b","c","d","e")

mydata<-data.frame(variables, pat1, pat2,pat3, pat4, pat5)
mydata<-t(mydata)
```

I translate my columns to rows and I get the correct table, but numbers are not doubles

```
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
variables "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
pat1      "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
pat2      "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" 
pat3      "1"  "3"  "5"  "7"  "9" 
pat4      "-5" "-3" "-1" " 1" " 3"
pat5      "12" "14" "16" "18" "20"
```

How shall I get doubles for my pat values?

Comment: By transposing, the data.frame is converted to matrix and matrix can hold only one class.  Your dataset has mixed class.  So, the matrix class will be converted to 'character'  If you need to get doubles for pat values, don't take the variable column while transposing. i.e. `m1 <- t(mydata[-1]); colnames(m1) <- mydata[,1]`

Comment: How do you want to use your data? You can try `split`